# Load form into panel ExtJ 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have in the main page with two principal parts :

- in the left part : I have panel that contains one button (to simplify).
- in the center part : I have an other panel, which contains the workspace.

My problem is that I want to load a form in the workspace when the user click the button.

**Sample of code :**

**in My Viewport I have this :**

```
 ....
 items : [{
    title : 'Principal Menu',
    layout : 'auto',
    width : '15%',
    height : '100%',
            items : [{
        xtype : 'button',
        text  : 'Load form',
        id    : 'loadIHM'
        }]
},{
        title : 'Espace de travail',
    layout : 'auto',
    width : '85%',
    height : '100%',
    id : 'workspace',
    items : [{
        html : '<b>Here to load Form</b>',
    }]
}
 ....
```

**and in My Controller I have this :**

```
    loadUserManager: function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        var ws = Ext.getCmp('workspace');
        //removeall -> ok
        ws.removeAll();
        var contro = this.getController('App.View.viewport');
        //View is not null
        var view = contro.views[0];
        //add doesn't work!!
        ws.add(view);
        ws.doLayout();

    }
```

finally I get this error in the developer tool (chrome)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'floating' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly thanks @Geromino for your answer, I have found somthing similar to your code :

**Changes in the Controller :**

```
loadUserManager: function() {
    var ws = Ext.getCmp('workspace');
    ws.removeAll();
    var moduleController = this.getController('App.Controller.MainController');
    moduleController.init();
    var moduleView = Ext.create(moduleController.views[0]);
    ws.add(moduleView);
    ws.doLayout();
}
```

Hop this help others.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this problem is because you are not *creating* the form (which would give it a `floating` property).

Instead of referencing it like: `var view = contro.views[0]`

Try: `var view = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyFormPanel')` (however you define your formpanel view)